# MATLAB: Track all possible variables

Tags: matlab, debugging

I Need to understand a very Long matlab file.
It is very tedious to put Breakpoints everywhere.

I wondered if there is an Option to track **every possible** variable at once ?
Something that would maybe store each variale in a text sheet and diaplays how they Change througout the code...

There are many many variables.
What I want to do is to create a scribt, where I can Input a list of variable names. The script then tracks those variable names within the program and exports them every time they Change.

**Input:** List of variables and programm Name (other script)

**Content:** Tracks variable in the Programm

**Output**: Table with tracked variables

Name_variable_1 |Value at line...|Value at line...|Value at line...

Name_variable_2 |Value at line...|Value at line...|Value at line...

.

.

.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a breakpoint you can hover over a variable and check its value...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe save the workspace periodically and then make a seperate MATLAB script that graphs the changes of the variables or writes out a text file for it?
I assume you're familiar with MATLAB, but just to be safe:
http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Just append the variable's contents to a text file or save the entire workspace and parse it later.

Comment: great idea! There are many many variables... so.. I updated my question.... please have a look.

Comment: to pass a function to another function you can use the @ operator http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/pass-a-function-to-another-function.html
And to access the workspace, maybe you can create a function around your script, essentially making your file a nested function. Then the workspaces should be shared and you can access it, if my understanding of the workspaces is correct.

Comment: i found a post on how to share data between workspaces. http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html
hope that helps